# Split a number to individual digits in javascript using basic methods

Tags: javascript

```js
var count = 0;
var arr = [];

function Split(number) {
  if (Math.floor(number / 10) > 0) {
    for (var count = 0; count < number.toString().length; count++)
      arr[count] = number % 10;
    number = Math.floor(number / 10);
  }
  return arr;
}
document.write(Split(2345))
```

It's returning 5,5,5,5 while I expected the result to be 2,3,4,5
Please tell me what part went wrong. Thank you!

Comment: document.write( (2345).toString().split("") );

Comment: (number).toString() converts the number into string representation. string.split("") splits the string into an array, passing a blank delimiter "" splits the string into individual characters.

Comment: Can you please explain your own algorithm in English? What exactly is your approach?

Comment: Why `Math.floor(number / 10) > 0` rather than the much simpler `number > 10`?

Comment: @Synthetx But this approach is not using the function I wrote? Sorry I am really confused but it seems like I don't need the function to display 2,3,4,5 by your approach

Comment: You forgot to put brackets around the second statement of the for loop `(number = Math.floor(number / 10);`, so only the first statement is executed repeatedly, the second is only executed once.

Comment: @slider for example the number is 2345, I will first split the last digit and put it to the first position of the array, and returns to the second last digit, repeat the same, until number is less than 10.

Comment: @RobG Yes that sounds much better, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
for (var count = 0; count < number.toString().length; count++)
  arr[count] = number % 10;
number = Math.floor(number / 10);
```

Only the first statement is included in the for loop, the second only runs after the for loop ends. You need braces around both statements so both run on each iteration.

```
for (var count = 0; count < number.toString().length; count++) {
  arr[count] = number % 10;
  number = Math.floor(number / 10);
}
```

But you'll still get the wrong result because you reset the limit for *count* on each iteration. Set it once at the start.

```js
var count = 0;
var arr = [];

function Split(number) {
  if (Math.floor(number / 10) > 0) {
    for (var count = 0, countLen = number.toString().length; count < countLen; count++) {
      arr[count] = number % 10;
      number = Math.floor(number / 10);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
document.write(Split(2345));
```

Comment: hum rather : `for (var count = number.toString().length; count > 0; count--)`

Comment: Thank you. May I ask what does countLen mean? Is Len a method? (Sorry if the question is stupid 
I

Comment: @JiangYuxin no it is not a method, it is a variable that is set to the length of the number.toString()

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. If number changes in the loop won't every variable involved number be changed automatically?

Comment: @SimonDehaut—yes, I was trying to keep close to the OP. :-)

Comment: @JiangYuxin—the second expression in the initiation part of a *for* loop is evaluated on every loop, so `number.toString().length` is evaluated on every loop. *number* keeps getting shorter in the loop so by the time *count* gets to 2, number is only 2 digits long and the loop stops.